# Apache commons-validator not validating gmail

Tags: java, android, apache-commons

I compiled Apache commons-validator 1.4.1 in my Build.gralde, with the purpose of validating emails. Thinking this was a more Solid Approach to email validation.

```
compile "commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1"
```

And when I try to run this, It returns True. While this email is False.

```
EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid("name@gmail");
```

Why is this so?

Comment: On your Realm question, the problem is most likely that you are manually sending/receiving event, and there is no guarantee that the UI thread Realm instance has evaluated all its queries asynchronously yet (after which it bumps the version). To force synchronous evaluation, you can use `realm.refresh()` when you've received the event.

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce for the help. I later found out It was a threading issue with the way I implemented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this issue is only with version 1.4.1, I updated to latest version 1.6 and validations works accordingly.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/changes-report.html

Comment: Exactly what I also wanted to say. There have been several bug fixes regarding the Email validator, e.g. in version `Release 1.5.1 – 2016-04-30`